# Wordpress cookie to highlight new posts?

Tags: wordpress, cookies

I have an aggregator site in wordpress, and was thinking about a way to show new  post for visitors. I don't use log-ins, so would be from plain visits. My thougth was to divide new post by a line below. Not sure how though.

Any suggestion on where to start? My site: http://www.skatevids.me

Answer (score 0):

this is a fairly generic/difficult to answer question for Stack Exchange. Not entirely sure if it's a good match to be honest, but maybe I can help you formulate one that would be.

So load your webpage and then right click in your browser. If you're using Chrome or Firefox, you'll want to click "Inspect Element." I'm not sure what the command is for other browsers, but hopefully you have access to Chrome or Firefox.

Okay, so once you inspect the element, you'll see what's called the DOM (Document Object Model. And if you click through that a bit, you'll see something like

I'd look into CSS child/sibling selectors (eg http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) and see if maybe there's  way to highlight the most recent, say, 6 posts. It's something to look into as a possibility, any way, and if it looks promising, you might want to give it a shot and come back with a question specific to that. As it is, there's about 50+ ways I could think of accomplishing this, some more realistic than others, depending on how your theme works. I think you'll have a lot more like getting an answer that works for your website if you try to think through some ways of doing it and check back with those

If you do that, some added info on how your theme works would be useful.... is that a widgetized home page? Are you telling your theme to display those posts there, instead of something else? If so, how are you specifying that? What is the meaning of "New post"?  Less than XYZ days old? Most recent ABC posts? Something else?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, something to think about. I´ve been fielding around with css a bit, but since i don't actually display a post per se, then some things won't work. I tried a a:visited on the links to display what has been clicked, but that only work of the link was clicked to be opened in a new page/tab, and not just to load the video.

Comment: Based on this I though selectors wouldn't work, only way i could thin of for that to work was with anchor links, which i don't wanna do. So i tought cookies would be the way to go, and i would wanna have it based on when the visitor was there the last time. But new post based on the day, would be great too.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, you can use the [Highlight New Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/highlight-new-posts/) plugin for this.

It sets a cookie with the time of the visitor's last visit. If it returns, it'll show a "NEW" label after the title of posts that have been published after their last visit.